# Access/VBA - Creating an new table with grouped records

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I've been thinking about my problem and researched here and the on the internet. I don't seem to get a step further...

I have a database with different tables. One of them is like a client table. Every client has to send in forms (up to 3) each months, this is in a second table.

It looks somewhat like this:

```
**tblReportedFiles**
ID Month Form
1 201803 1
2 201803 1
1 201803 2
2 201804 2
3 201804 3
1 201804 1
```

My goal is to create code that will create a new table with the following dataset:

```
    clientID - ReportingMonth - Form 1 - Form 2 - Form 3
        1         201803         true     true     false
        2         201803         true     false    false
        3         201803         false    false    false
        1         201804         true     false    false
        2         201804         false    true     false
        3         201804         false    false    true
```

I just cant to get anything to work. I playe around with SQL and VBA but nothing goes into the right direction.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What have you actually tried?

Comment: you can use the access the function IIF. Adding 3 new columns IIF(Form=1 , 'true', 'false') as Form1, IIF(Form=2 , 'true', 'false') as Form2, IIF(Form=3 , 'true', 'false') as Form3. Then you can apply some aggregation function like max or min to remove the null values on these new columns, groupping by clientId and ReportingMonth

Comment: @DKyleo I have been trying to group the data with different queries and then to combine them. I didn't even know where to begin to put this in code.

Comment: @Jaime thank you for your reply, I found a solution based on Erik's post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a crosstab (pivot) query to achieve this. That's more flexible than the solution suggested by Jaime, since this will auto-create columns as new forms are added to the table.

```
TRANSFORM CBool(Count([Form]))
SELECT ID, [Month]
FROM tblReportedFiles
GROUP BY ID, [Month]
PIVOT "Form " & [Form]
```

We're both transforming `Form` to the count cast to a boolean, and pivoting by `Form`. That means if the specific `Form` value occurs for the grouping variables, the count will be 1, and that's cast to a boolean `True`, and if it doesn't, the count will be 0, which casts to a boolean `False`.

Comment: OK, I had to look up what a crosstab actually is. Thanks for the idea :) What exactly is [Form] in my context?

Comment: The column named form. This query should run on your provided table definition.

Comment: of course, my bad! When I try it I get the message that Null isn't allowed. I checked and could find any Null or Zero values. Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: Well, sounds like there are null values somewhere. Find them using `ID Is Null Or [Month] Is Null Or [Form] Is Null. If you want a more specific answer, you will have to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I checked for it and wasn't able to find any Null values, but I think that wasn't the problem. I looked up CBool and realized that it makes a boolean check, but in my DB it's not a bool value but text.

That being said, I managed to adjust and tweak your query and got the result I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: And thanks for the "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" link. This is still very new and all guidance is welcome :)